# Count string pattern by group in R

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I'm trying to obtain a grouped count of a certain string within a dataframe using R, but as of yet have not been able to come up with a solution. Here's some sample data and the code that I've attempted to use so that you have an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish, as well as further explanation below:

```
simpson <- structure(list(season = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), episode_title = c("Simpsons Roasting on an Open Fire", 
"Bart the Genius", "Homer's Odyssey", "There's No Disgrace Like Home", 
"Bart the General", "Moaning Lisa", "The Call of the Simpsons", 
"The Telltale Head", "Life on the Fast Lane", "Homer's Night Out", 
"The Crepes of Wrath", "Krusty Gets Busted", "Some Enchanted Evening", 
"Bart Gets an \"F\"", "Simpson and Delilah", "Treehouse of Horror", 
"Two Cars in Every Garage and Three Eyes on Every Fish", "Dancin' Homer", 
"Dead Putting Society", "Bart vs. Thanksgiving", "Bart the Daredevil", 
"Itchy & Scratchy & Marge", "Bart Gets Hit by a Car", "One Fish, Two Fish, Blowfish, Blue Fish", 
"The Way We Was", "Homer vs. Lisa and the 8th Commandment", "Principal Charming", 
"Oh Brother, Where Art Thou?", "Bart's Dog Gets an \"F\"", "Old Money", 
"Brush with Greatness", "Lisa's Substitute", "The War of the Simpsons", 
"Three Men and a Comic Book", "Blood Feud", "Stark Raving Dad", 
"Mr. Lisa Goes to Washington", "When Flanders Failed", "Bart the Murderer", 
"Homer Defined", "Like Father, Like Clown", "Treehouse of Horror II", 
"Lisa's Pony", "Saturdays of Thunder", "Flaming Moe's", "Burns Verkaufen der Kraftwerk", 
"I Married Marge", "Radio Bart", "Lisa the Greek", "Homer Alone", 
"Bart the Lover", "Homer at the Bat", "Separate Vocations", "Dog of Death", 
"Colonel Homer", "Black Widower", "The Otto Show", "Bart's Friend Falls in Love", 
"Brother, Can You Spare Two Dimes?", "Kamp Krusty", "A Streetcar Named Marge", 
"Homer the Heretic", "Lisa the Beauty Queen", "Treehouse of Horror III", 
"Itchy & Scratchy: The Movie", "Marge Gets a Job", "New Kid on the Block", 
"Mr. Plow", "Lisa's First Word", "Homer's Triple Bypass", "Marge vs. the Monorail", 
"Selma's Choice", "Brother from the Same Planet", "I Love Lisa", 
"Duffless", "Last Exit to Springfield", "So It's Come to This: A Simpsons Clip Show", 
"The Front", "Whacking Day", "Marge in Chains", "Krusty Gets Kancelled", 
"Homer's Barbershop Quartet", "Cape Feare", "Homer Goes to College", 
"Rosebud", "Treehouse of Horror IV", "Marge on the Lam", "Bart's Inner Child", 
"Boy-Scoutz 'n the Hood", "The Last Temptation of Homer", "$pringfield (or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love Legalized Gambling)", 
"Homer the Vigilante", "Bart Gets Famous", "Homer and Apu", "Lisa vs. Malibu Stacy", 
"Deep Space Homer", "Homer Loves Flanders", "Bart Gets an Elephant", 
"Burns' Heir", "Sweet Seymour Skinner's Baadasssss Song"), imdb_votes = c(3734L, 
1973L, 1709L, 1701L, 1732L, 1674L, 1638L, 1580L, 1578L, 1511L, 
1539L, 1716L, 1567L, 1638L, 1588L, 1786L, 1457L, 1381L, 1366L, 
1324L, 1522L, 1402L, 1340L, 1687L, 1392L, 1329L, 1241L, 1413L, 
1264L, 1243L, 1257L, 1684L, 1246L, 1379L, 1223L, 1798L, 1274L, 
1302L, 1446L, 1452L, 1262L, 1369L, 1243L, 1194L, 1618L, 1291L, 
1213L, 1365L, 1179L, 1176L, 1272L, 1637L, 1201L, 1165L, 1233L, 
1233L, 1176L, 1160L, 1227L, 1414L, 1339L, 1747L, 1194L, 1394L, 
1293L, 1163L, 1240L, 1595L, 1350L, 1445L, 2028L, 1153L, 1176L, 
1268L, 1209L, 1827L, 1105L, 1122L, 1234L, 1080L, 1269L, 1416L, 
2010L, 1476L, 1479L, 1437L, 1132L, 1085L, 1270L, 1308L, 1274L, 
1202L, 1123L, 1171L, 1187L, 1505L, 1191L, 1116L, 1143L, 1118L
), us_viewers_in_millions = c(26.7, 24.5, 27.5, 20.2, 27.1, 27.4, 
27.6, 28, 33.5, 30.3, 31.2, 30.4, 27.1, 33.6, 29.9, 27.4, 26.1, 
26.1, 25.4, 25.9, 26.2, 22.2, 24.8, 24.2, 26.8, 26.2, 23.9, 26.8, 
23.9, 21.2, 20.6, 17.7, 19.7, 21, 17.3, 22.9, 20.2, 22.8, 20.8, 
20.6, 20.2, 20, 23, 24.7, 23.9, 21.1, 21.9, 24.2, 23.2, 23.7, 
20.5, 24.6, 23.7, 23.4, 25.5, 17.3, 17.5, 19.5, 17.2, 21.8, 18.3, 
19.3, 19, 25.1, 20.1, 22.9, 23.1, 24, 28.6, 23.6, 23, 24.5, 23.8, 
25.2, 25.7, 22.4, 25.5, 20.1, 20, 17.3, 19.4, 19.9, 20, 18.1, 
19.5, 24, 21.7, 18.7, 20.1, 20.6, 17.9, 20.1, 20, 21.8, 20.5, 
18.2, 18, 17, 14.7, 19.7)), .Names = c("season", "episode_title", 
"imdb_votes", "us_viewers_in_millions"), row.names = c(NA, -100L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

char_counts <- simpson %>%
  group_by(season) %>%
  str_count(episode_title, "Homer")
```

So I first grouped the data by season and then I'm trying to count the total number of times the word "Homer" appears in the title of any episode in a given season.

Any suggestions for where I've gone wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Best,
Curtis

Comment: a) you have to store somewhere what you get from `str_count`. b) your column is not `title`, but `episode_title`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the column name misspecification. I copied that code from a previous version of my script and forgot that I changed the name from 'title' to 'episode_title'. I edited the code above to reflect that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add a new variable to each row you need to use the `mutate` function. The `group_by` is not needed unless you want to summarize by group:

```
simpson %>%
    mutate(homer_count = str_count(episode_title, 'Homer'))

# A tibble: 100 x 5
   season episode_title                     imdb_votes us_viewers_in_millions homer_count
    <int> <chr>                                  <int>                  <dbl>       <int>
 1      1 Simpsons Roasting on an Open Fire       3734                   26.7           0
 2      1 Bart the Genius                         1973                   24.5           0
 3      1 Homer's Odyssey                         1709                   27.5           1
 4      1 There's No Disgrace Like Home           1701                   20.2           0
 5      1 Bart the General                        1732                   27.1           0
 6      1 Moaning Lisa                            1674                   27.4           0
 7      1 The Call of the Simpsons                1638                   27.6           0
 8      1 The Telltale Head                       1580                   28             0
 9      1 Life on the Fast Lane                   1578                   33.5           0
10      1 Homer's Night Out                       1511                   30.3           1
# ... with 90 more rows
```

If you instead want to count how many times `Homer` is used per season, you `group_by` and then use `summarize` to produce a new variable with one row per group:

```
simpson %>%
    group_by(season) %>%
    summarize(homer_count = sum(str_count(episode_title, 'Homer')))

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  season homer_count
   <int>       <int>
1      1           2
2      2           2
3      3           4
4      4           2
5      5           7
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)

simpson %>%
  mutate(counts = str_count(episode_title, "Homer")) %>%  # count matches for each row (vectorised function)
  group_by(season) %>%                                    # for each season
  summarise(sum_counts = sum(counts))                     # sum counts

# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#   season sum_counts
#    <int>      <int>
# 1      1          2
# 2      2          2
# 3      3          4
# 4      4          2
# 5      5          7
```